# Mapping an array of strings to an array of strings

Tags: arrays, lambda, f#

I'm getting this error when I try to compile

> The operator 'expr.[idx]' has been used on an object of indeterminate
>   type based on information prior to this program point. Consider adding
>   further type constraints

This is the code

```
let convertFile fileName =
    let arrayToTransaction (arr: string[]) =
        arr 
        |> Array.map (fun x -> splitStr [|"\n"|])
        |> Array.map 
            (fun x -> { 
                        date = DateTime.Parse(x.[1]);
                        payee = x.[0].Substring(0, x.[0].IndexOf(','))
                        category = "Everyday Expenses: Groceries/Food"
                        memo = "Parsed with my F# parser"
                        outflow = Single.Parse(x.[2].Substring(str.IndexOf('-') + 1))
                        inflow = 0.0f
                      })
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to do exactly what the error message says, and add a type annotation:

```
|> Array.map 
            (fun (x:string[]) -> { 
                        date = DateTime.Parse(x.[1]);
                        payee = x.[0].Substring(0, x.[0].Index
```

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately, it says. `This expression was expected to have type
    string -> string []    
but here has type
    string []`. Which doesn't make a lot of sense to me because the array is a collection of strings..

Comment: the problem is your `splitStr` call one line earlier. You're not passing in the `x` string at all.

Comment: Yes I figured it out literally the same time as you posted. I thought the lambda would "pipe" the x to `splitStr` alas it doesn't it seems.

Comment: Note: This is why it is a good idea to give line numbers of errors

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the problem was this line

```
    |> Array.map (fun x -> splitStr [|"\n"|])
```

Because `splitStr` is a helper function that takes two arguments, however I thought that the lambda would "pipe" the  `x` into it but it doesn't work that way I noticed so changing it to this worked.

```
    |> Array.map (fun x -> splitStr [|"\n"|] x)
```

Comment: Right, nothing of that sort gets done implicitly. You can make it point-free if you do this though: `Array.map (splitStr [|"\n"|])`.